# Does EOS Loki work on the Surface 3 (non-pro)?

Tags: release-loki, surface-tablet

I have elementaryos-0.4.1-stable.20170814 and made the install disk.

It stops when trying to install the OS to disk. When I try to run the OS directly from the Live Disk it is able to boot successfully into the OS, but then hangs at the desktop. On the Touch Cover, keyboard, touchpad, and touchscreen input don't respond.

The odd thing is that the touchpad DOES work momentarily right as the OS boots to the desktop, but then stops responding a couple seconds later.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, Microsoft is not so open about their bootloader and drivers, so its already pretty hard to install anything but Windows, but there is an even bigger issue with your config.

You're using a non-pro surface 3, this means you're running an ARM processor, not an x64 processor. Elementary is, sadly, not available for this kind of processors.

You could try any Linux distro that is ARM compatible.

Comment: The Surface 3 actually has an Intel Atom processor: https://www.phonearena.com/phones/Microsoft-Surface-3_id9538